# how to edit /etc/hosts/ file on nginx docker image

Tags: python, docker, nginx

I am using docker-compose for my python web app. I am using nginx as one of service. Currently I am running on localhost and it is working fine. Now, instead of localhost I am trying to use domain name as `server_name www.mywebapp.com` and I also need to edit `/etc/hosts` file to add `127.0.0.1 www.mywebapp.com`, Although file already has default entry as `127.0.0.1 localhost`.

- File: default.conf.template

```
server {
    
    listen 8080;
    server_name ${DOMAIN_NAME};

    client_max_body_size 8G;

    location / {       
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass http://web:5000;
    }
}
```

- File: nginx Dockerfile

```
ARG NGINX_IMG
FROM $NGINX_IMG
ARG DOMAIN_NAME
ENV DOMAIN_NAME=$DOMAIN_NAME
USER root
# RUN sed -i 's/127.0.0.1       localhost/127.0.0.1       localhost $DOMAIN_NAME/' /etc/hosts
RUN echo "127.0.0.1       $DOMAIN_NAME" >> /etc/hosts 
COPY deploy/docker/proxy/default.conf.template /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.template 
USER nginx
CMD ["/bin/sh" , "-c" , "envsubst '$DOMAIN_NAME' < /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"]
```

Output:

- On running, `sed` it gives error as busy operation
- On running, `echo` it executes successfully, but on checking from nginx container terminal `cat /etc/hosts` No modification for domain name
- On checking `default.conf` the `server_name` gets updated by `envbust` as `server_name www.mywebapp.com`

As getting error to modify `/etc/hosts` file unable to access through domain name.

How to edit  `/etc/hosts` file on nginx docker image?

Comment: The hosts file is one of the parts of network setup that's managed by Docker at container startup time; you can't modify it in your image, but the linked question describes options to add entries to it when you run the container.  Consider whether an external DNS service would be more scalable and maintainable than trying to manually copy around `/etc/hosts` files.

Comment: (Also remember that 127.0.0.1 in Docker is usually the current container; it is a different `localhost` than 127.0.0.1 on the host system.)

Comment: Hi David, Thanks. I Agree, As I am new to DevOps and learning the deployment process, now exploring AWS.